# Error loading Lightning App Builder -

Tags: lightning, app-builder

I;m trying to access to the App Builder in salesforce and I'm getting the next error:

[image]

Anybody know what is the cause or how to make it work?

Comment: Do you have the Aura Inspector installed? Try disabling it.

Comment: it was the problem but with a different plugin I think. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems the Lightning inspector plugin for google Chrome was causing this issue

[image]

I disable it and now I can work with the App Builder. Thanks @Kristian

Comment: Should be fixed in the next release of the Lightning Inspector.

Comment: New release of the Lightning Inspector (http://sfdc.co/inspector) should not have this problem.